# include id in url to pass to another model

Tags: cakephp

I have a model relationship with Product hasmany Page.  When I add a new product and then go to the view, i can add a new prodpage to that product.  However, clicking the link does not pass the current Product id to the prodpages/add page.  I would like it to do that so that when you go to add the prodpage the associated Product ID is already selected based on the previous product you were viewing.

I think it comes down to editing the link in the Product View and passing the id to append after the prodpages/add/.  is that correct? here it is:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Prodpage'), array('controller' => 'prodpages', 'action' => 'add'));?> </li>
```

How can I include the product id to that?

when It comes to the Prodpages controller.. here is what I got so far for the add function..

```
public function add($product_id) {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Prodpage->create();
            if ($this->Prodpage->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The prodpage has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The prodpage could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $products = $this->Prodpage->Product->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('products'));
        $this->data['Prodpage']['product_id'] = $product_id; 
    }
```

will that work for the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, just add it to your link

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('New Prodpage'), array(
  'controller' => 'prodpages', 
  'action' => 'add',
  $product_id
));
```

Your missing more of your view, but this assumes that your view has a variable `$product_id`.